# Xcode 4.2 Core Data Model Versioning Issues

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsattributedescription

I have a model that I created a long time ago. Everything works great, until I try to add a new model version. At runtime none of my attributes' User info key/value pairs show up. Reverting back to the previous xcdatamodel version works fine, only the new xcdatamodel doesn't work.

The User Info keys show up in the editor, but at runtime they do not appear. The `- (NSDictionary *)userInfo` on `NSPropertyDescription` returns an empty dictionary every time. This happens on all my entities if I change any user info key. If I create a new model version it works fine, until I mutate the User Info collection in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, I had the same problem. See http://twoshotsofcocoa.com/?p=51 for the solution.